# Apache 301 Redirect from www.subdomain to domain folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-redirect, redirect

I want to redirect from www.blog.domain.com

to

www.domain.com/blog/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Those rules look fine to me, assuming:

1. You've put them in an htaccess file in the document root of your `www.blog.domain.com` domain
2. You don't have other rules before the redirect rules that may be handling the request before it reaches the redirect
3. The rewrite module is loaded into your apache instance
4. The document root is configured with at least `AllowOverride Fileinfo` (or ALL)